# Search for arbitrary strings and not just prefix in T-SQL

Tags: sql, string, ssms

My requirement is to be able to search strings in column which match any number of characters in order  against the passed string.

For example:

If I passed `Hello` and if my table column has `Tell` than query should select `Tell` for matching `ll` in two strings. 
While it can give results for match of single character as well since there can be no order in it.
but if its two characters matching ,than those two have to be consecutive, not picked out randomly from any position i.e in `you` and `our`, its a two character match because `ou` is present in both strings in same order.
What I have considered so far is using `Substring` in my query until the length of loop i.e

```
while begin(@counter <= lengthOfPassedString)
   select Name from column where column LIKE + '%' + SUBSTRING(@parameterFromUser, 1, @counter) + '%' 
end
```

But above code can look for `brook` in `Westbrook` but can not look for `rook` from `krook` if I passed `krook` as the string and `westbrook` was present in column of table.

Shall I consider using nested `while` loop with counter for starting position of SUBSTRING method as well? I understand the performance will be (lengthofstring)^2 but would love to get to know a better approach for this.

Comment: So if you use param1 = 'abc', any words containing the letters `a` or `b` or `c` should be returned? or does it have to match at least two: `ab` or `bc`? Can we make assumptions about the maximum length of the string passed in? Then you could use a very long OR to brute force every two characters along the input parameter without a loop

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: It has to match atleast one or more than that. Yes, we can make assumptions of the maximum of length of string passed in. I understand the brute force technique and that's what I meant when I said nested while loops in my question. inner loop maintaining counter for end position and outer loop for starting position but is there any better way to do it?

Comment: actually one or more, because then I will be taking percentage of matched and unmatched characters so all that matters is how many characters matched. if its two characters matching ,than those two have to be consecutive, not picked out randomly from any position i.e in you and our, its a two character match because ou is present in both strings in same order.

Comment: hmmm it really helps to explain all of it up front... my solution below is not of any use in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to match at least two characters, here is a brute force method which does not require loops:

It only works for inputs up to 9 characters long. I think you get the idea.

This is the only non loop solution that I can think of. You might be able to do some crazy `FOR XML` thing but I think that's over the top.

You can also use a CTE or select from a system table to generate a tally table and use that just like a loop. Let me know if you would like to see that solution.

```
declare @p varchar(50)
SET @p = 'Krook'

select * from 
(
select 'Westbrook' G
UNION ALL
select 'Tell' G
UNION ALL
select 'Something' G
) F
where (
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,1,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,2,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,3,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,4,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,5,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,6,2) + '%','%%','')
OR
f.G LIKE REPLACE('%' + substring(@p,7,2) + '%','%%','')
)
```

Comment: McDermaid : Thanks for it but that's exactly what a nested while loop would do, i.e change starting position . I get this substring approach and performance here would be same i.e (lengthofstring)squared but may be some inbuilt function or Full text search in any possible way can do better than that that I may be completely unaware of?

Comment: What is FOR XML approach? I am clueless about it.Would like to know more about how it works.

Comment: The difference is that this is a subtable/view that can be joined to other tables and possibly optimised by the query optimiser. A procedural solution generally cannot.

Comment: oh,can not imagine helping it here with select query that is inside of a Multiline TVF. I have no understanding of it so kind of unsure about it.

Comment: The FOR XML thing is just a hunch. You can for example use it to pivot data and there might be a way to also use it to do what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206696/using-for-xml-in-t-sql-to-pivot-data. But I can't think of a specific way. I will also suggest a set based solution (i.e. a tally table) over a procedural solution (a loop)